# Format combox in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, combobox

In my table I have one unique customer number per many invoice numbers. I only want to see that unique customer number with a summary of all the invoices on the print preview screen and see the unique customer number associated with the invoices on the list of the combo box using the drop down arrow. How do I do that? I am using Access 2007

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your first problem would be addressed with writing a report to show the result of a query that would list the summary details of all invoices tied to a customer number.  This number would be fed to the query from your calling form.

Your second issue sounds like a combo box on your form that would be populated by a SQL SELECT statement in your control source that would pull information on invoice numbers tied to the customer number presented on the form.

I'm being general as I don't know your implementation, and you have failed to provide any context and previously tried-and-failed code.